# Accessing TFS using Web Services

Tags: web-services, tfs

I am wondering if there is a way to access TFS using web services in order to pull user stories.  In the end state what I want to happen is that, user comes into my website, type in a user story id click a button, which then pulls the user story title, description, and who its assigned to into my website.  I don't want them to know where the story is from just want them to be able to pull it. Any ideas on how I can do this would be great.

Update: Let me expand on my question as I have done a little more research.  Has anyone tried to use OData with TFS in order to query or pull stories. Arethere any good examples that exist.

Thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does TFS 2010 have web services one can use to query check-ins, work items, etc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122427/does-tfs-2010-have-web-services-one-can-use-to-query-check-ins-work-items-etc)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227376/is-there-any-documentation-on-tfs-web-services

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682140/are-tfs-2010-a-k-a-microsoft-alm-2010-web-services-exposed-documented

Comment: Ultimately, you want to use either the .NET or the Java SDK for TFS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your web site is .net, you want to use the TFS SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(v=vs.80).aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/73f79348-0b37-406b-aa3b-a63d3837951b

Comment: SDK? Really? The question was about web services, not old-school, compiled binary applications.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest standing up the TFS ODATA services. These services are currently available to all CodePlex projects, and the source is available for download. The services can be hosted internally with minimal work, or you could consider a cloud hosting option like Azure.

Here is a post from Brian Keller with more info and guidance. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2011/10/26/odata-service-for-team-foundation-server-2010-v1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) is documented at MSDN. Among other things you can

- access TFS user profiles
- get completed builds and kick them off
- manipulate work items